# Treating a passed function argument in a windows batch file as an environment variable

Tags: function, batch-file, environment-variables

So I want to check if an environment variable exists in a windows batch file, and if it does exist, does it point to a valid path.

I'm passing two variables to a function, the first is the string representing the environement variable, the second is a default path to set it to.  I want to check to make sure it isn't already set though.  If it is already set, I just want to check that the path is good and report if it's not.  This is what I have:

```
CALL:SET_PATH MY_ENV "C:\My\Path"

:SET_PATH
IF NOT DEFINED %1 (
  IF EXIST %2 (
    ECHO ______________________________________________
    ECHO %1=%2
    SETX %1 %2
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO %1 environment variable was not set, the path did not exist:
    ECHO %2
  )
) ELSE (
  IF NOT EXIST %1 ( <-- How do I evaluate this as an environment variable instead of a string so I can get the path?
    ECHO %1 environment variable points to a path that does not exist:
    ECHO %1 <-- Same thing here
  )
)
GOTO:EOF
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL 
CALL:SET_PATH MY_ENV "C:\My\Path"
GOTO:EOF

:SET_PATH
IF NOT DEFINED %1 (
  IF EXIST %2 (
    ECHO ______________________________________________
    ECHO %1=%2
    SETX %1 %2
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO %1 environment variable was not set, the path did not exist:
    ECHO %2
  )
) ELSE (
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  IF NOT EXIST "!%~1!" (
    ECHO %1 environment variable points to a path that does not exist:
    ECHO !%1!
  )
  endlocal
)
GOTO:EOF
```